# Convert a number entered by a user in PowerShell into an array by counting

Tags: arrays, powershell

I have a PowerShell script I am using to automate creating volumes on a SAN. The script prompts the user to enter the pertinent information: number of volumes, volume size and naming pattern. Next it should run a command on the array to create the volumes using the information provided. Here is where I am stuck. Right now the script asks the user to specify the number of volumes to create. For example let's say the user enters the number 4. I a stuck on how to take 4 and make it an array 1,2,3,4 or 7 to 1,2,3,4,5,6,7. Maybe there is an easier way to do this via counting or some other function. I am new to scripting, so any help is greatly appreciated.

```
# Define the number of volumes to create
$num_vols = read-host "Please enter the number of volumes"

# Define naming pattern
$vol_name = read-host "Please enter the volume naming pattern"
```

What I wanted to do was create a function that would basically run something like:

```
# Run command to create volumes on array
foreach ($i in $num_vols){
    & "command to execute" $vol_name + $i
}
```

Thanks for the suggestions. I am now using:

```
# Run command to create volumes on array
foreach ($i in 1..$num_vols){
    & "command to execute" $vol_name"."$i
}
```

Works perfectly! I can now create X volumes named VolName.1, VolName.2 and so on, where X is the number of volumes entered by the user.

Comment: `1..$num_vols | % { .... }`

Comment: Based on your question I am not entirely sure what you are asking. Do you want to simply execute the command some number of times or do you actually need a number of array elements ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the range operator (`..`):

```
foreach ($i in 1..$num_vols) { ... }
```

Or the range operator like this:

```
1..$num_vols | ForEach-Object { ... }
```

Or you can use a traditional `for` loop:

```
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $num_vols; $i++) { ... }
```